# Formatting strings into groups of 3 digits by periods

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I know I can format strings using the `String.Format()` method. Is it possible to format like this?

Example:

> string: 1568
>      formatted: 1.568
>
> string: 168794521
>      formatted: 168.794.521
>
> string: 987
>      formatted: 987

Sorry that I can't make myself more clear.

Comment: Are you wanting .'s instead of ,'s when formatting the strings?

Comment: its worth take a look at http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string someNumericValue = "168794521";
int number = int.Parse(someNumericValue); // error checking might be appropriate
value.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("el-GR"));
```

This will put points in for thousand specifiers.

It's possible that if you want this, your culture may already do this.

Answer (score 9):

You can format a *number* that way, but not a string.  For example, if you have an integer value, you can use:

```
int value = 168794521;
string formatted = value.ToString("N0");
```

With the proper culture, this will format as shown.

If you are using a string, you would need to convert it.  You could also explicitly provide a culture to guarantee "." as a thousands separator:

```
int value = Int32.Parse("168794521");
string formatted = value.ToString("N0", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Comment: I believe OP is looking to put a *decimal points* at every thousandth place.

Comment: @JamesJohnson yes, and using a culture like 'de-DE' will do that - some cultures use '.' for thousand separators and ',' for decimal points.

Comment: @JamesJohnson That's why my second example explicitly specifies a culture that would do this...

Comment: @Reed It would be my guess that it is because your solution does in fact give 168.794.521,00 not 168.794.521 which is what the question asks for. Small technicality, but not exactly what he wants, nor does it stop people from upvoting a slightly incorrect answer.

Comment: @KreepN Thanks - Fixed.  I always think its weird that Int32.ToString would do that - always forget it ;)

Comment: @Reed It's an honest mistake, but it would seem that's why downvotes are only -2, so you don't get wrecked for silly stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that. [SteveX has written a great blog post on string formatting](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/). You could also look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kathykam/archive/2006/03/29/564426.aspx), and the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).

You probably want to look at the bottom of this documentation in the "More Resources" section for more info about different types of standard format strings.

Here is the relavant part from the SteveX blog on formatting numbers:

- Currency `{0:c}`
- Decimal (Whole number)   `{0:d}`
- Scientific `{0:e}`
- Fixed point `{0:f}`
- General `{0:g}`
- Number with commas for thousands `{0:n}`